# How to call and save contact in Java ME?

Tags: java-me, save, call, contacts, midp

I am doing a program using j2me and the last window in the program has a form that contains name of the place, number and location.

I want to know:

1. if there is any way to call for the number which appears in the window?
2. if there is any way to save the information (name and number) in the contact?

any tutorials or examples applied this feature << because I searched a lot and I didn't find something useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the midlet.platformRequest("tel:[telephone number]") to make the call. As far as accessing contact in the phone or saving contacts to the phone's address book, your phones needs JSR 75 API functionality and you might also require to sign the build